# Why fetch does not include credentials everytime with option {credentials: "include"}?

Tags: javascript, django, cookies, django-rest-framework, fetch

I have been trying to fetch data from my `djangorestframework` api verifying through cookies. Before reaching to the main problem,

- My computer IP on LAN: `192.168.1.50`
- Running localhost at port 80: `127.0.0.1`
- Running django at port 8000: `192.168.1.50:8000` *- (tried vice versa as well: 127.0.0.1:8000)*

Now, assuming my `django` is running on `192.168.1.50:8000`, I figured out that if I send `fetch` request to `djangorestframework` from `192.168.1.50` the cookies are attached with the request.

Django's settings.py:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    "corsheaders",

    'users',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://192.168.1.50",
    "http://127.0.0.1",
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    "accept",
    "accept-encoding",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "dnt",
    "origin",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
]
```

Fetch method from JS,

```js
fetch("http://192.168.1.50:8000/user/auth/", {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
}).then(r => {
    console.log(r.json());
})
```

---

### Sending request from `192.168.1.50`,

From `192.168.1.50`'s (from chrome browser),

Response Header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.1.50
Allow: OPTIONS, GET
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: application/json
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Date: Wed, 15 Dec 2021 #:#:# GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.10
Vary: Accept, Cookie, Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Request Header:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: hello=world; csrftoken=value; sessionid=value  # Cookies are passed
DNT: 1
Host: 192.168.1.50:8000
Origin: http://192.168.1.50
Referer: http://192.168.1.50/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36
```

---

### Now same request from `http://127.0.0.1`,

Response Header: *- (unchanged)*

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1
Allow: OPTIONS, GET
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: application/json
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Date: Wed, 15 Dec 2021 #:#:# GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.10
Vary: Accept, Cookie, Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Request Header: *- (changed)*

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json  # No cookies
DNT: 1
Host: 192.168.1.50:8000
Origin: http://127.0.0.1
Referer: http://127.0.0.1/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36
```

---

### Please tell me what am I doing wrong and why is this happening?

Thank you.

Comment: @sideshowbarker you mentioned "
Nothing in this question as currently written relates directly to CORS". Could you say why is this happenning and what should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you set SameSite to None, Chrome will not sending cookies at all unless the Secure flag is set, and therefore only over HTTPS.  The exception is for same site requests.

This will explain why your session and csrftoken cookies get sent from 192.168.1.50 but not 127.0.0.1. I don't know how your hello=world cookie was set.  If that also had SameSite=None, then it would not get sent either.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. I've come across the same issue when working with VueJs3 and fetch. It turned out that fetch doesn't send credentials when the headers "Content-Type: application/json" or "Accept: application/json" are  being used. Comment it and see if it works.